# How to do conditional; styling in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scss-lint

I have React functional component in which I have a button and I'm checking whether the button is in viewport or not, and I'm storing it as a boolean in "isElementVisible".

I want to do conditional styling here, if isElementVisible === false then I want to make it sticky else leave it as it is.

desired styling when isElementVisible === false :

```
.apply-btn{
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
                width: 17rem;
            }
            @media (max-width: 599px) {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                left: 50%;
            }
        }
```

Component:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment,@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const CalcOutput = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [isElementVisible, setIsElementVisible] = useState(false);
    const applyNowButton = document.getElementById('calc-applyNowBtn');
    const isElementInViewPort = (element: HTMLElement) => {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return(
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );
    }
    const handleScroll = (event: Event) => {
        if(applyNowButton !== null) {
            const isVisible = isElementInViewPort(applyNowButton)
            isVisible ? setIsElementVisible(true) : setIsElementVisible(false);
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return (
                <button className="apply-btn" id="calc-applyBtn">
                     Apply
                </button>
    );
};

export default CalcOutput;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make another css class (called `apply-btn-sticky` for example) that applies when a condition is satisfied:

```
.apply-btn-sticky {
  @media {
     position: sticky;
  }
}
```

and then set the `className` for your button based on that condition:

```
<button className={this.isElementVisible ? "apply-btn" : "apply-btn apply-btn-sticky" id="calc-applyBtn">
     Apply
</button>
```

You can reuse much of the styling from your `apply-btn` class since all you want to change is make the position sticky.

Answer (score 1):

As answered already, you can use ternary operators.
But if you already have multiple classes applied and want one class to be conditional, you can use template strings.

```
<div className={`btn btn-primary ${isActive ? 'active' : ' '}`}> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with ternary operators, as you can see the below code.

```
<div className={!isElementVisible ? 'sticky' : 'navbar'} />
```